# Unable to understand why the absolute positioned element doesnt stay at the intended position when scrolled?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

Why  element with class `child2` (position absolute) does not stay at at the intended position when parent element class `overflowTest` (position relative, overflow scroll ) is  scrolled.

What I am assuming when I scroll is there is no any change on parent element (height,width, postion) and so no affect on child element class `child2` , only the child element class `child1` moves. But what I actually  notice is `child2` is also moved. I am unable to properly understand / picture what is happening,

-- * css *--

```
#overflowTest {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  height:70%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position:relative;
  background:green;
}
.child1{
    height:800px;
    width:10px;
    background:red
}
.child2{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

-- * html * --

```
<div id="overflowTest">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`child2` is positioned absolute, but relatively to the nearest ancestor with `position: relative`, so when you scroll the container (here `#overflowTest`), `child2` will also be scrolled because "it's in a relation (`relative`) with the container".

If you moved `position: relative` from `#overflowTest` to `body`, then scrolling `#overflowTest` won't affect `child2` as it would be in relation to the body element (so scrolling body would affect `child2`).

here's the code

```
<style>
body {
    position: relative;
}
#overflowTest {
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    height:70%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background:green;
}
.child1{
    height:800px;
    width:10px;
    background:red
}
.child2{
    height:10%;
    width:10%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
</style>
<div id="overflowTest">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use: `position: fixed`

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled

~ [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

and `position: sticky` is sometimes useful

I recommend visiting the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) link, it is very well explained there, and if you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask in the comment

Comment: sorry, I have corrected it now

Comment: @sql_dummy I've updated my answer, hope it helps now